# Is it haram to wear make-up?

Tags: halal-haram, cosmetics

Arabic make-up is quite popular but as far as I'm concerned, Muslim women should be as humble as possible in their style. Is make-up allowed? If so, to what extend?

Comment: check the link below about makeup. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HEa6rmojJ4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, Islam values human tendency to beauty a lot and considers it something related to our [Prima facie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prima_facie). It's in our nature to have tendency to beauty and to look for it.

[Imam Ja'far al-Sadiq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja%27far_al-Sadiq) said:

> (اِنَّ اللَّهَ جَمیلٌ وَ یُحِبُّ الْجَمالَ.(۹۰
>
> God is beautiful and likes beauty.

So, wearing make-up is allowed as long as it is limited to [maharem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahram) and there's no intention of a parade of beauty. Otherwise it'll provoke lust of men which is strongly proscribed by Islam. So the intention of make-up counts.

Comment: Who is Imam Sadeq? Do you mean rasulullah?

Comment: @ashes999: I've added a reference for more information.

Comment: The imam is Ja'farul Sidiq

Comment: This actually *is* a hadith of rasulullah, recorded in Saheeh Muslim and Riyaad As-Saliheen. See: http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1#612

Comment: Beauty is very subjective.  What is beauty according to Allah?  I personally think a person without makeup looks more beautiful.

Comment: I would add that some make-ups contain unsafe and dangerous substances for our health; So not all of them are *halal*.

Comment: And also beauty in Islam is the beauty  of the behaviour, not of the aspect looking.

Answer (score 4):

I have no references for this, but I would say a woman is *only* allowed to wear make up in the presence of her husband.  You asked to what extent: the answer is, just enough to make you feel beautiful in front of your husband.  As with perfume, make up should not be worn in public.

The hadith here saying perfume of the women should not have any odour.

> Pointing to the collar of his shirt al-Hasan (al-Basri) said: The perfume used by men should have an odour but no colour, and the perfume used by women should have a colour but no odour. Sa'id said: I think he said: They interpreted his tradition about perfume used by women as applying when she comes out. But when she is with her husband, she may use any perfume she wishes.

<sup>source: [here](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/34#29)</sup>

The interpretation is given by the Great Tabie (Who see Sahabah's) Al-Hasan Al-Basri.

In another hadith, Prophet Muhammad (Sallallahu Alaihi Wa -sallam) strictly prohibited the use of perfume by women which have odour or scent.

> None of you women should use perfume when you are present at the isha prayer

<sup>source: [here](http://sunnah.com/urn/404670)</sup>

If using perfume in prayer in the Great mosque of Nabawi with the presence of Rasul-ul-Allah was not allowed, how can it be allowed in these age of fitnah and with random persons in random areas and time?

Comment: Please add references either to primary texts or scholarly answers.

Comment: I have heard one should present themselves before God as they would with any 'important' human. For men, it is mustahabb to wear perfume when going to the mosque; for women, it is mostly considered to be not allowed.

Comment: yes the women is not allowed to wear perfume out.  because women do not need to attract men.

Comment: Beauty is very subjective. What is beauty according to Allah? I personally think a person without makeup looks more beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

It is not allowed to go out in public wearing any makeup unless your face is veiled and the makeup won't be seen. It seems common these days the Muslimah will say "but I'm not wearing it to attract men" but how do you know they won't be attracted to you? (It is illogical to wear a hijab (loose flowing non see through dress covering everything except face and hands) and red lipstick!). The makeup is only allowed to be worn in front of mahrems and the husband.

https://islamqa.info/en/72390
"It should be noted that it is not permissible for a woman to wear makeup in front of non-mahram men, because she is commanded to cover her face in front of them and because wearing makeup is an adornment that leads to fitnah. If she does that and then prays, she will have the reward for her prayer but she will have the burden of sin for tabarruj (wanton display).

It says in Fataawa al-Lajnah al-Daa’imah (17/129): There is no reason why a woman should not adorn herself by wearing makeup on her face, or kohl, or doing her hair in a manner that does not make her resemble kaafir women, but it is also essential that she cover her face in front of men who are not her mahrams. End quote.

It also says (17/128): Using kohl is allowed in Islam, but it is not permissible for a woman to show any of her adornment, whether kohl or anything else, to anyone other than her husband or mahrams, because Allaah says (interpretation of the meaning):

“…and not to reveal their adornment except to their husbands…”

[al-Noor 24:31]"

Answer (score -1):

Haram in Islam has a definite list as stated in Quran an none is allowed to change them. Allah prohibited touching Haram and Halal for example at the beginning of Sourah Tahrim. So wearing make up is not Haram as not mentioned so in Quran but going in order to display your finery and beauty is discouraged in Quran:

> وَقَرْنَ فِي بُيُوتِكُنَّ وَلَا تَبَرَّجْنَ تَبَرُّجَ الْجَاهِلِيَّةِ
>   الْأُولَىٰ ۖ وَأَقِمْنَ الصَّلَاةَ وَآتِينَ الزَّكَاةَ وَأَطِعْنَ
>   اللَّهَ وَرَسُولَهُ ۚ إِنَّمَا يُرِيدُ اللَّهُ لِيُذْهِبَ عَنكُمُ
>   الرِّجْسَ أَهْلَ الْبَيْتِ وَيُطَهِّرَكُمْ تَطْهِيرًا (احزاب/33)
>
> Remain in your houses; and display not your finery, as did the pagans
>   of old. And perform the prayer, and pay the alms, and obey God and His
>   Messenger. People of the House, God only desires to put away from you
>   abomination and to cleanse you.

Comment: It is not discouraged, It is prohibited. The two words are very different.

Comment: I have to agree with @Anwar You must be trying to soften the blow with the 'discouraged' word but you should not be ashamed of what ALLAH has prohibited. This is for our own good. We are very careful with our wording these days because people will accuse us of Anti-feminism. We do not care about such labels. Quran clearly mentions in this ayah 'Remain in your houses and display not your finery'. And today if we advocate this point, people point fingers at us for being narrow-minded. I say do not worry about such moronic taunts.

Comment: @SorrelVesper Congratulate you on your courage and true view about not being ashamed of  what ALLAH says: "ALLAH is not ashamed before the truth." (Al-Ahzab 33/53). But there is a difference here: I am not ashamed of the subject at all but I'm afraid of "forging against ALLAH a lie" (Al-Anaam 6/21). Prohibition (Haram) is a special word and is of a higher degree of prohibition. Usually this kind of prohibition is stated by "Hurrimat" in Quran (e.g. An-Nisa 3/23). We should be careful while using the word. We may not assign "Haram" to whatever that is said not to be done in Quran.

Comment: I am sorry. You are right. But you have to look at the Ahadeeth and actions of the Ummhatul Momineen. Then we will understand if its allowed for women to show their beauty to non-mehrams and go out in public with such make-up etc. and we will then see if its discouraged or forbidden.