# Is it haram to wear makeup when wearing a hijab?

Tags: hijab

A little bit of context before the question: I were at a restaurant and pretty much every woman there was wearing makeup which is common and I don’t really see it as a bad thing but according to some it is bad. So then I saw that a group of women were wearing hijab and makeup and I was confused.
The main point of the hijab is for modesty but wearing makeup basically takes away the modesty part as makeup just seems to be a form of attracting attention. Is it permissible to wear makeup and wear a hijab or not?

Answer (score 2):

> It was narrated that Al-Ash'ari said: "The Messenger of Allah [SAW]
> said: 'Any woman who puts on perfume then passes by people so that
> they can smell her fragrance then she is an adulteress.'"
>
> Sunan an-Nasa'i 5126 https://sunnah.com/nasai:5126

I think makeup is like perfume except that makeup is for sense of sight whereas perfume is for sense of smell.

Answer (score 0):

Is makeup forbidden during hijab?
The pattern of makeup should be determined by custom; That is, the general public, people who are in a person's place of residence, if they consider something to be makeup and the woman has that makeup, she should cover it from the non-mahram look. For example, no one calls a simple and ordinary cream makeup. But in general, what is traditionally considered as adornment and makeup, should be covered from non-mahrams.

Ref: https://www.delgarm.com/religious/religious-orders/213005-

Answer (score -1):

If your thinking that she shouldn’t wear make up just because it’s a woman only area and sectioned then should she be OK with not wearing a hijab as well? You wear a hijab in public so that men don’t feel sexual desires when looking at you. Wearing make up defeats the purpose of wearing a hijab. There is no grey area with religion. It’s either yes or no, right or wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works, and please cite sources and thoroughly answer the question asked.

Comment: It's also not as simple as "yes and no"; e.g. kohl.  [Is it haram to wear make-up?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/144/is-it-haram-to-wear-make-up).

Answer (score -2):

Ok first, Make up is haram, Now just wait a second it is haram because Allah said "And we created the human in best shape/form" And for me makeup is like covering Allah creation tho it also ruins the face.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

The permissibility of wearing makeup while wearing a hijab (Islamic head covering) can vary depending on different interpretations within Islamic jurisprudence and cultural norms. There isn't a clear-cut answer applicable to all situations, as opinions on this matter may differ among Islamic scholars and within different Muslim communities.

Some scholars may argue that wearing makeup in public, even with a hijab, could attract undue attention from unrelated men and thus contradict the principles of modesty (hayaa) outlined in Islam. Others may view makeup as permissible as long as it is applied modestly and not intended to draw excessive attention or violate the principles of Islamic modesty.